# Azure AI Search sample index for .msg email files

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-ai

Does anyone know how to create Azure AI Search indexes for email .msg files?

I have been able to find sample indexes for JSON content but can't seem to find samples that index email content.

I would like to be able to create an index based on the common email properties: From, To, CC, Subject, Sent Date, and body.

I believe it would be something like:

```
    {
        "name": "email-index",  
        "fields": [
            {"name": "From", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "filterable": true},
            {"name": "To", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
                "fields": [
                "address1",
                "address2"
                ]
            }
            {"name": "CC", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
                "fields": [
                "address1",
                "address2"
                ]
            }
            {"name": "BCC", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
                "fields": [
                "address1",
                "address2"
                ]
            }
            {"name": "DateSent", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer": "en.lucene"},
            {"name": "Body", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
        ]
    }
```

I can't fin samples for the .msg email fields to construct the index.

Comment: what   .msg email fields do u want

Answer (score 1):

The below code  is for creating or updating or searching email data an index in Azure Cognitive Search using the Azure SDK for [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-python-create-load-index?tabs=azure-cli%2Clinux-install%2Clinux-run).

```py
import sys
import json
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import SearchIndex, SimpleField, SearchableField

# Azure Search service endpoint and admin key
service_name = "YOUR_SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME"
admin_key = "YOUR_SEARCH_SERVICE_ADMIN_API_KEY"
endpoint = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/"

# Index name and schema
index_name = "email-index2"

# Define the fields for the schema
fields = [
    SimpleField(name="EmailId", type="Edm.String", key=True, searchable=True),
    SimpleField(name="From", type="Edm.String", searchable=True, filterable=True),
    SimpleField(name="To", type="Collection(Edm.String)", searchable=True, filterable=True),
    SimpleField(name="CC", type="Collection(Edm.String)", searchable=True, filterable=True),
    SimpleField(name="BCC", type="Collection(Edm.String)", searchable=True, filterable=True),
    SimpleField(name="DateSent", type="Edm.String", searchable=True, filterable=True),
    SimpleField(name="Subject", type="Edm.String", searchable=True, filterable=True),
    SimpleField(name="Body", type="Edm.String", searchable=True, filterable=True)
]

# Instantiate the SearchIndex object with the defined fields
index = SearchIndex(name=index_name, fields=fields)

# Instantiate the SearchIndexClient
credential = AzureKeyCredential(admin_key)
index_client = SearchIndexClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=credential)

# Create or update the index
try:
    index_client.create_or_update_index(index=index)
    print(f"Index '{index_name}' created or updated successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

[image]
Supported data types  of Azure AI [Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types#edm-data-types-used-in-azure-ai-search-indexes-and-documents)

```json
 {
    "name": "email-index",  
    "fields": [
        {"name": "EmailId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": true},
        {"name": "From", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true},
        {"name": "To", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": true},
        {"name": "CC", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": true},
        {"name": "BCC", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": true},
        {"name": "DateSent", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true},
        {"name": "Subject", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true},
        {"name": "Body", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true}
    ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

- Azure Files indexer  with Azure AI [Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-file-storage-integration#supported-document-formats)

**In azure portal :**

[image]

- Indexing file contents and metadata in Azure Cognitive [Search](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cognitive-search-blob-metadata/tree/main).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried using the index fields you suggested, but I am not able to query using these fields.  
{
  "search": "{{search}}",
  "select": "From, To, CC, BCC, DateSent, Subject, Body",
  "searchFields": "Subject, Body",
  "count": true
}

Comment: Thank you... I still have not found the answer.

Comment: Ensure that the field names used in your query ("From," "To," "CC," "BCC," "DateSent," "Subject," "Body") exactly match the field names defined in your Azure AI Search index schema

Comment: {
    "search": "*",
    "filter": "DateSent ge 'start_date' and DateSent le 'end_date'",
    "select": "From, To, CC, BCC, DateSent, Subject, Body"
}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an index and indexer that allows me to query based on the following fields:
metadata_content_type
metadata_message_from
metadata_message_from_email
metadata_message_to
metadata_message_to_email
metadata_message_cc
metadata_message_cc_email
metadata_message_bcc
metadata_message_bcc_email
metadata_creation_date
metadata_last_modified
metadata_subject

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-metadata-properties

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).